# Kubernetes cluster setup on single VM for Angular frontend, express for API and Mogo for a backend

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to setup a Kubernetes cluster on a Ubuntu VM which is there on a lab server. I want to access the application with VM IP over the network with some basic org. level SSO authentication.
My application setup is something like - front end is running on Angular, API is on Express and Backend is mongo DB. I believe I need create 3 deployment, 3 service and persistent storage manifest files.
I need some guidance which has the manifest declarations which will help me quickly bring up the cluster. Any additional details which I need consider is of great help to me

Comment: SO's format doesn't accept tutorial posts. Pleas read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

For first question setting up single node k8s there are multiple options like minikube,k3s, kind, mircrosk8s etc

For your micro services you can check 12 factors [principles](https://dzone.com/articles/12-factor-app-principles-and-cloud-native-microser)

Comment: Setup I have to do it with 2 VM's. So my plan is to start with one to keep both master and worker on one Node. But definitely I need this done with 2 Nodes at least to realize all the K8 benefits.

Comment: You can use microk8s